# Need assistance regarding ALAssetsLibraryAccessGloballyDeniedError

Tags: ios, objective-c, alassetslibrary

> **[ALAssetsLibrary Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AssetsLibrary/Reference/ALAssetsLibrary_Class/Reference/Reference.html)**
>
> Special Considerations: This method will fail with error
>   ALAssetsLibraryAccessGloballyDeniedError if the user has not enabled
>   Location Services (in Settings > General).

1. Where is location services in Settings > General?
2. I reset the location and privacy and disabled location services in Settings > Privacy > Location Services and here is my code that still **don't** give me `ALAssetsLibraryAccessGloballyDeniedError` error.

`

```
-(void)requestAccessForAssetsLibrary {
    ALAssetsLibrary *aLib = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc]init];
    void(^assetsGroupEnumerationBlock)(ALAssetsGroup*, BOOL*) = ^(ALAssetsGroup *groups, BOOL *stop) {
        *stop = YES;
        NSDictionary *alAuthDict = @{@"alAssetsAuthStatusDictKey" : [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",[self getALAssetAuthorizationStatus]]};
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]postNotificationName:@"alAssetsStatusNotificationName" object:nil userInfo:alAuthDict];
    };
    void(^failureBLock)(NSError*) = ^(NSError *error) {
        NSDictionary *alAuthDict = @{@"alAssetsAuthStatusDictKey" : [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",[self getALAssetAuthorizationStatus]]};
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]postNotificationName:@"alAssetsStatusNotificationName" object:nil userInfo:alAuthDict];
    };
    [aLib enumerateGroupsWithTypes:ALAssetsGroupAll usingBlock:assetsGroupEnumerationBlock failureBlock:failureBLock];
}
```

`

Comment: Go in Settings--->Privacy---> Photos and check the status of your app  and after ios 6 it is not mandatory that location services should be on to access AssetsLibrary

Comment: @Leena thanks for replying, but its no where define that after ios 6 it is not mandatory that location services should be on to access AssetsLibrary.

Comment: Because with ios 6 apple has added AuthorizationStatus for AlAssetLibrary. Refer this link https://developer.apple.com/LIBRARY/ios/releasenotes/General/RN-iOSSDK-6_0/index.html for more info